# how to connect preferences and readings to tthe user_id in the users table in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a project I've been working on what I'm trying to figure out.. I have a login component that gets a specific user out of an array and I'm trying to grab the correct preferences for that user here is what I have...

```
getPreference = () => {
    const {
      user_id,
      timesPD,
      chkCarbs,
      chkInsulin,
      typInsulin,
      chkBP
    } = this.state.preference;
    const { preferences } = this.state;

    if (
      preferences.length > 0 &&
      preferences.find(preference => preference.user_id === user_id)
    ) {
      this.setState({
        preference: {
          ...this.state.preference,
          user_id: this.state.preferences.find(
            preference => preference.user_id === user_id
          ).user_id,
          timesPD: this.state.preferences.find(
            preference => preference.user_id === user_id
          ).timesPD,
          chkCarbs: this.state.preferences.find(
            preference => preference.user_id === user_id
          ).chkCarbs,
          chkInsulin: this.state.preferences.find(
            preference => preference.user_id === user_id
          ).chkInsulin,
          typInsulin: this.state.preferences.find(
            preference => preference.user_id === user_id
          ).typInsulin,
          chkBP: this.state.preferences.find(
            preference => preference.user_id === user_id
          ).chkBP
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Incorrect ID');
    }
}
```

can anyone help me with what i'm doing wrong

Comment: so what feedback are you getting? What is going wrong actually? Give us some context.

Comment: `preferences` appears to be an object, not an array, something doesn't quite align with how you are accessing it. Can you provide the majority of the component code?

Comment: can you post how your preferences variable will look like and what is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out I'm supposed to pass it the user id in the handle Login function... thank you and I may have some more questions that I am trying to work through